# How to find a value in a table with no identifiers? (Python, Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a webpage with a table with many rows. A user will give me a number (15308) which can be found in the top line with the first `<td>` tag, and this is the only information I will have. I want to be able to use this number to find the data between the `<th></th>` tag (more specifically the 0), but only for the table row. For example, I attached two table rows and I want the `<th>` data using the number 15308, but not the `<th>` data from the table row that has the number 15309 in it's first `<td>`. Any help is appreciated!
Desired Output: 0

```
<tr>
<td><a href="http://sdb.admin.uw.edu/timeschd/UWNetID/sln.asp?QTRYR=SPR+2019&amp;SLN=15308">15308</a></td>
<td nowrap="">INFO   101  </td>
<td>A </td>
<td align="CENTER">LC</td>
<td>SOCIAL NETWORKING   </td>
<td align="CENTER"> 150</td>
<td align="CENTER"> 150</td>
<td align="CENTER"> 250</td>
<th align="CENTER">  0</th><td align="CENTER"> 229</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://sdb.admin.uw.edu/timeschd/UWNetID/sln.asp?QTRYR=SPR+2019&amp;SLN=15309">15309</a></td>
<td nowrap="">INFO   101  </td>
<td>AA</td>
<td align="CENTER">LB</td>
<td>SOCIAL NETWORKING   </td>
<td align="CENTER">  25</td>
<td align="CENTER">  25</td>
<td align="CENTER">  26</td>
<th align="CENTER" style="">  2</th><td align="CENTER">  21</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @Fareed : Which value you want to get and what xpath you have tried?

Comment: @DirtyBit I'm trying to obtain the value of 0 found in <th> </th>

Comment: @FareedMabrouk see if the answer posted below helps?

Comment: @FareedMabrouk What should be the output from your latest edited question?

Comment: @DirtyBit I should only be getting 0

Comment: @DirtyBit But if the user gives me 15309, I should be getting 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Following code :**

```
userValue='15308'
all_td_th_of_row = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[normalize-space()='" + userValue + "']//following-sibling::td|th")
i = 0
while i<len(all_td_th_of_row) : 
    print(all_td_th_of_row[i].text)
    i=i+1
```

Comment: There are multiple <th> </th>  on the page, how can I choose the one that is contained in the <tr> </tr> that also contains the number 15308?

Comment: @FareedMabrouk : what is 15308 ?

Comment: @FareedMabrouk : 15308 is it the value which you want to get ? can you give me exact html or link of your page

Comment: How can I give you exact html? If I give you a link it won't work as it requires a login @PritamMaske

Comment: I think my issue is more clear now, I edited the question

Comment: @FareedMabrouk : check now

Comment: @FareedMabrouk : you can pass the value 15308 using variable as well if you are getting it from some where else

Comment: 15308 is a variable I already have, and I would like to get all the info from the table row that 15308 is contained in if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Something I have always found beautiful, using [`beauitfulsoup`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/):

<s>Using the `xpath="1"` as an attribute:</s>

```
line = '''<tr><td><a href="http://sdb.admin.uw.edu/timeschd/UWNetID/sln.asp?QTRYR=SPR+2019&amp;SLN=15308" style="">15308</a></td>
<td nowrap="">INFO   101  </td>
<td>A </td>
<td align="CENTER">LC</td>
<td>SOCIAL NETWORKING   </td>
<td align="CENTER"> 150</td>
<td align="CENTER"> 150</td>
<td align="CENTER"> 250</td>
<th align="CENTER" style="" xpath="1">  0</th><td align="CENTER"> 229</td>
<td></td>
</tr>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(line, 'html.parser')
xpathTh = soup.find('th',  attrs={'xpath': '1'})
print(xpathTh.text.strip())
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
0
```

**EDIT**:

To get all the values from the attrib:

```
line = '''<tr><td><a href="http://sdb.admin.uw.edu/timeschd/UWNetID/sln.asp?QTRYR=SPR+2019&amp;SLN=15308" style="">15308</a></td>
<td nowrap="">INFO   101  </td>
<td>A </td>
<td align="CENTER">LC</td>
<td>SOCIAL NETWORKING   </td>
<td align="CENTER"> 150</td>
<td align="CENTER"> 150</td>
<td align="CENTER"> 250</td>
<th align="CENTER" style="" xpath="1">  0</th><td align="CENTER"> 229</td>
<th align="CENTER" style="" xpath="1">  1</th><td align="CENTER"> 229</td>
<th align="CENTER" style="" xpath="1">  2</th><td align="CENTER"> 229</td>
<td></td>
</tr>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(line, 'html.parser')
xpathTh = soup.find_all('th',  attrs={'xpath': '1'})

for elem in xpathTh:
    print(elem.text.strip())
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
0
1
2
```

**EDIT 2**:

Considering you only want the `xpath value` if the `anchor tag` inside the `td` (inside `tr`) has a value of `15308`:

```
line = '''<tr><td><a href="http://sdb.admin.uw.edu/timeschd/UWNetID/sln.asp?QTRYR=SPR+2019&amp;SLN=15308" style="">15308</a></td>
<td nowrap="">INFO   101  </td>
<td>A </td>
<td align="CENTER">LC</td>
<td>SOCIAL NETWORKING   </td>
<td align="CENTER"> 150</td>
<td align="CENTER"> 150</td>
<td align="CENTER"> 250</td>
<th align="CENTER" style="" xpath="1">  0</th><td align="CENTER"> 229</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://sdb.admin.uw.edu/timeschd/UWNetID/sln.asp?QTRYR=SPR+2019&amp;SLN=2222" style="">22222</a></td>
<td nowrap="">INFO   101  </td>
<td>A </td>
<td align="CENTER">LC</td>
<td>SOCIAL NETWORKING   </td>
<td align="CENTER"> 150</td>
<td align="CENTER"> 150</td>
<td align="CENTER"> 250</td>
<th align="CENTER" style="" xpath="1">  1</th><td align="CENTER"> 229</td>
<td></td>
</tr>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(line, 'html.parser')

trElems = soup.find_all('tr')
toFind = '15308'

for tr in trElems:
    val = tr.select('td a')[0].text
    if toFind == val:
        xpathTh = tr.find_all('th', attrs={'xpath': '1'})
        for elem in xpathTh:
            print(elem.text.strip())
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
0
```

**EDIT 3**:

Continuing from comments:

```
line = '''<tr>
<td><a href="http://sdb.admin.uw.edu/timeschd/UWNetID/sln.asp?QTRYR=SPR+2019&amp;SLN=15308">15308</a></td>
<td nowrap="">INFO   101  </td>
<td>A </td>
<td align="CENTER">LC</td>
<td>SOCIAL NETWORKING   </td>
<td align="CENTER"> 150</td>
<td align="CENTER"> 150</td>
<td align="CENTER"> 250</td>
<th align="CENTER">  0</th><td align="CENTER"> 229</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://sdb.admin.uw.edu/timeschd/UWNetID/sln.asp?QTRYR=SPR+2019&amp;SLN=15309">15309</a></td>
<td nowrap="">INFO   101  </td>
<td>AA</td>
<td align="CENTER">LB</td>
<td>SOCIAL NETWORKING   </td>
<td align="CENTER">  25</td>
<td align="CENTER">  25</td>
<td align="CENTER">  26</td>
<th align="CENTER" style="">  2</th><td align="CENTER">  21</td>
<td></td>
</tr>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(line, 'html.parser')

trElems = soup.find_all('tr')
toFind = '15308'

for tr in trElems:
    val = tr.select('td a')[0].text
    if toFind == val:
        xpathTh = tr.find_all('td')[7]
        print("For the value: {}, The result is {}".format(toFind, xpathTh.find_next('th').text.strip()))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
For the value: 15308, The result is 0
```

Comment: I believe this would work for a one row table but the page is a large table with many rows, I am finding the 15308 number through "find_element_by_link_text" but that is all I can do, I was wondering if maybe there is a way to go forward a certain number of elements using a for loop?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think I'm explaining my issue clearly, I will edit my post to try and give it more clarity

Comment: I think I made my issue more clear in the new edited question, I am trying to get just the <th> data from one table row. Thank you for sticking with me!